# Spring Reactor - Emit last item

Tags: spring, kotlin, flux, reactor

I have an endpoint where I call a Spring spring service to get status of an order. The service returns and Enum with the values: `Processing`, `Completed` or `Error`.

```
@GetMapping(value = ["/{orderId}/state"], produces = [MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE])
fun orderState(@PathVariable("orderId") orderId: Long): Flux<OrderStateDetails> {
    return Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .take(30)
        .map { orderService.orderState(orderId) }
        .takeWhile { orderStateDetails -> orderStateDetails.state == OrderState.Procession }
}
```

I'm using a Flux to implement a low tech polling until state is no longer `Processing` and no longer than 30 seconds. I wan't the endpoint to return:

- Processing
- Processing
- Processing
- Completed

But the `takeWhile` is not emitting the last item `Completed`. I tried to add `.also { orderService.orderState(orderId) }` and `.concatWith(Flux.just(orderService.orderState(orderId)))` but that will make an extra unnecessary call and also does not emit the item.
How can I make it emit the last items as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `takeWhile()` which does not give you the !result of your predicate, you should use `takeUntil()`

Here's a simple example in Java, but you can easily adapt it to Kotlin and your code:

```
Flux.just("Processing", "Processing", "Processing", "Completed")
                .delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(1000))
                .takeUntil(status -> status.equals("Completed"))
                .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

This will print the following output:

```
Processing
Processing
Processing
Completed
```

So I think this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: Ahh yes this is exactly what I was looking for. The documentation also says: `Relay values from this Flux until the given Predicate matches. This includes the matching data (unlike takeWhile).`.